# Doing sql-esque queries on .csv files

Tags: sql, macos, ubuntu, csv

Is it possible to make queries like "SELECT A.a, A.b, B.a, B.c FROM Aa.csv A INNER JOIN Bb.csv B ON A.a = B.a" on csv files -
 * Using MS Office or a gratis/cheap alternative
 * On OSX
 * Without having to have access to or create a real sql database and import the csv files

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use the Perl's [DBD::CSV](http://p3rl.org/DBD%3a%3aCSV) module.